Does the shell provide access to all services that an OS can provide?
I'm an Undergraduate CS student learning about Computer Architecture and OS. Naturally, we learnt about Unix and Linux. Recently, I came across the term "shell". My understanding and question is the following please.

We can access the services provided by the OS via a terminal.

(Q) So are ALL services provided by Unix accessible via the terminal ? That is, the Unix developers created the terminal, with the purpose to have all services of the Unix OS be accessed through it ?

With every article I read about the kernel, it says that the kernel is THE MOST IMPORTANT PART of any OS. Then,

(Q) Can I understand that in Unix/Linux, all services that it provides, is provided by the kernel ?
If this is TRUE, then, this means that all the services that Unix/Linux provides, is accessible by the shell. (Since the shell is the interface we use to access the kernel's services.)

You can probably see it this way: "allows" merely means that it is one of the components along the line. Obviously it doesn't mean that there are nothing else between a shell and the kernel. (The thing is, technically the shell is also just a userspace program and it is probably possible to e.g. have a shell builtin that issue ioctls like BLKDISCARD. It's just there is no reason to write such a shell.)

Please don’t ask multiple questions in one. Anyway, there are a few Qs&As here discussing kernels, terminals, and shells, I linked one of them to get you started.

Hi @StephenKitt, when you choose to specify "This question already has answers here", you need to specify which question, that question answers. I think you can already edit my question.
Thank you for the link, I've seen it but it doesn't clearly answer Q1, best I can do is make a guess from the different answers/comment.

Doesn’t the diagram answer it? It illustrates that (a) the shell doesn’t provide full coverage of the kernel’s features and (b) nothing else goes through it to access the kernel. Your question title mentions the shell, you first question in the question text talks about the terminal, and your third question talks about the kernel; it’s not clear which you’re interested in, which is why I didn’t edit it.

What do you think "service" means?  I think you don't have a clear enough understanding of unix architecture and what resource each piece manages to ask a clear question.

It does not give access to the graphical user interface. Except that you can start programs and control them from the shell. But it does not directly E.g Xeyes does not run in the text shell.

You know what, "terminal" isn't exactly a synonym to "shell". We can access the services provided by the OS via a terminal. I think this statement is really just more or less referring to the fact that, you interact with the computer with a keyboard (well CLI/TUI) and a display. It's probably not even talking about terminal emulators. (In some sense, I guess it implicitly considered the shell as well though.) But really, my suggestion is that, don't bother. People from the academia spits out vague sentences all the time. That's pretty much how academia works.

In other words, "services" here probably isn't talking about technical specifics like syscalls or different kinds of programs, but really just "what the computer can do for you". (I think one should be able to get the sense of that sentence after watching the first Alien movie...)

Hi @TomYan, the "services" here is meant as "all that you can do (via code) with the OS". So without the user having to write up their own OS, but simply writing lines of codes, that make use of or have control of the computer, based on what the installed OS has allowed you to do, e.g., syscall. The terminal here is the terminal emulator.
So in other words, when an OS is built, the developer does so in a way that allows the user to make use of the computational resources (e.g., have computer do certain tasks), with respect to the design of the OS.

The OS makes the intermediate tasks involved easier to do. So going back to the question, it is saying with all the services that the OS provides, can we access them simply through the terminal emulator ? The "services" meaning, whatever the kind of things that the OS developer has written for us to be able to do.
That's why I was asking "well, then, is the terminal emulator THE SOFTWARE for us to use, to access ALL services that the OS has provided for us to be able to do?"
